# Need Help Sorting ListView with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a Main Activity that holds a viewpager that contains three fragments. In each fragment is a listview populated by a custom adapter. I need the ability to sort by date, name and quantity (the fields that the listview shows)

Here is my Main Activity

```
    package com.bkbeesites.bkbeesalessheet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public ArrayList<Customer> packageData;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("BK Bee Sales - Pending Sales");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String dft = preferences.getString("default", "");
        if(!dft.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            if (dft.equals("package")){
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }else if (dft.equals("nuc")){
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }else if (dft.equals("queen")){
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            } else {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        }

    }

    public void showAddCustomer(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCustomer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void sortDate (View view){
        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
        Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
        Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();

       if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
           tab1.sortDate();
       }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1(), "Packages");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2(), "Nucs");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3(), "Queens");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else if (id==R.id.action_viewList){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SalesRecord.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Here is my Tab1 Class

```
package com.bkbeesites.bkbeesalessheet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    private CustomerAdapter customerAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "fragment_tab1";
    private ListView tab1ListView;
    private ArrayList<Customer> packageData = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView totalPackages;
    TextView totalGross;
    View rootView;
    public Tab1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        tab1ListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab1ListView);
        totalPackages = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.totalPackages);
        totalGross = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.totalGross);
        return rootView;


    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        updatePackageList();

    }
    public void updatePackageList() {
        packageData.clear();
        tab1ListView.setAdapter(null);
        int totalPackagesInt = 0;
        try {
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM packageCustomers", null);
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                   while (!c.isAfterLast()){
                        Customer cus = new Customer();
                        cus.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
                        cus.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                        cus.setPhone(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phone")));
                        cus.setEmail(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
                        cus.setQuantity(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("quantity")));
                        cus.setNotes(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("notes")));
                        cus.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                        packageData.add(cus);
                       totalPackagesInt = totalPackagesInt + cus.getQuantity();
                        c.moveToNext();
                    }

                }
            }
            customerAdapter  = new CustomerAdapter(this.getContext(), packageData);
            tab1ListView.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
            db.close();
            c.close();
            String totalPackagesText = totalPackagesInt + " Total Packages Reserved";
            totalPackages.setText(totalPackagesText);
            packageMath(totalPackagesInt);
            tab1ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Customer cus = new Customer();
                    cus = customerAdapter.getItem(position);
                    int sqlId = cus.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CustomerModel.class);
                    intent.putExtra("table", "packageCustomers");
                    intent.putExtra("id", sqlId);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        }
    }
    public void packageMath(int i){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(rootView.getContext());
        String p = preferences.getString("packagePrice","");
        if(!p.equals("")) {
            int price = Integer.parseInt(p);
            int totalGrossInt = i * price;
            String grossText = "Projected Earnings: $" + String.valueOf(totalGrossInt);
            totalGross.setText(grossText);
        } else {
            totalGross.setText("Edit Price Preferences");
        }
    }
    public void sortDate(){
        Collections.sort(packageData);
        tab1ListView.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
        updatePackageList();
    }


}
```

Here is my Customer Class

```
package com.bkbeesites.bkbeesalessheet;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Brett on 12/6/2017.
 */

public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>{
        public String name;
        private String email;
        private String phone;
        private int quantity;
        private String notes;
        private String date;
        private int id;
        private Date dateTime;


        public Customer (){

            this.name = "";
            this.email="";
            this.phone="";
            this.quantity=0;
            this.notes="";
            this.date="";
        }
        public Customer (int id, String name, String phone, String email, int quantity, String notes, String date) {

            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.notes = notes;
            this.date = date;
        }
    public Date getDateTime() throws ParseException {
        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        Date convertedDate = new Date();

            convertedDate = sdf.parse(date);

        return convertedDate;
    }
    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }
        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }
        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }
        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
        public String getNotes() {
            return notes;
        }
        public void setNotes(String notes) {
            this.notes = notes;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Customer o) {

        try {
            return getDateTime().compareTo(o.getDateTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }


    }
}
```

And Lastly, here is my CustomerAdapter

```
package com.bkbeesites.bkbeesalessheet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Brett on 12/6/2017.
 */

public class CustomerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Customer> mDataSource;


    public CustomerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Customer> items) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        mDataSource = items;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataSource.size();
    }

    //2
    @Override
    public Customer getItem(int position) {
        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }

    //3
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //4
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get view for row item
        View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        // Get title element
        TextView nameTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView quantityTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTextView);
        TextView dateTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        Customer cus = mDataSource.get(position);
        nameTextView.setText(cus.getName());
        quantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cus.getQuantity()));
        dateTextView.setText(cus.getDate());
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Sorry if that was a lot of unnecessary code but I'm a beginner here and did not know what you would want to see.

I'm trying to call Collections.sort when the Column Title Textview "Order Date" is clicked. The Data that contains the Customer objects is stored in an SQLite database (not sure if that's pertinent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a method in adapter class that should look like this;

```
 public void sort(){
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

if you don't want to create comparator every method call you can create variable of comparator.

```
private Comparator comp = new Comparator<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```

in this case you need to change sort method like;

```
public void sort(){
    Collections.sort(list, comp);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

whenever you want to sort in your activity class you need to call this sort method it will sort your list and update listview.
In your activity class you need to call method like below

```
adapter.sort();
```

Also if you want to compare according to other fields. You can create variable as

> private int sortType;

You should pass parameter to adapter class.

```
public void sort(int sortType){
    this.sortType = sortType;
    Collections.sort(list, comp);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and change the comparator field as below

```
 private Comparator comp = new Comparator<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
            switch(sortType){
                case 0: //By Name
                    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return o1.getQuantitiy() - o2.getQuantitiy();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    break;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I had problems updating the fragment's listview from the button on the activity and found out that my methods of doing that were wrong, so I set up the sort type selector in the preferences dialog. Otherwise, the sorting is working. Thank you, very much, Ergin.

Comment: Did my answer help you ?

Comment: if my answer was right for you please accept it as answer. Otherwise please add more information as comment

Comment: It did help. I'm past that in my app and I appreciate your help. Sorry this was my first question here so I didn't know I needed to accept it. Doing that now.